# Form loads with the minimal size (which displays only the title bar) rather than the size corresponding to the value set to its properties

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, size

I have a form which contains a `Menu Strip` docked to the top, a `Status Strip` docked to the bottom, and a `Panel` docked to fill the entire space between the aforementioned controls. I have set the attributes to the following values for the form:

During the design phase:

```
AutoScaleMode: Dpi
AutoSize: false
AutoSizeMode: GrowOnly
DoubleBuffered: true
SizeGripStyle: Show
```

During runtime (in the form's constructor):

```
// Calculate the default size of the window on the basis of the ratio of the dimensions of the window to the dimension of the screen resolution of the machine used in development as the default dimensions of the window is aligned to that of the machine used to design it    
this.Size = new Size(Screen.GetWorkingArea(this.Location).Size.Width * (widthOfWindowInDesignPhase /horizontalResolutionOfTheDisplayInDesignPhase), Screen.GetWorkingArea(this.Location).Size.Height * (heightOfWindowInDesignPhase / verticalResolutionOfTheDisplayInDesignPhase)); 
this.MinimumSize = new Size(this.Size.Width, this.Size.Height);
```

My first attempt to resolve this issue was to tinker around with the `AutoSize` and `AutoSizeMode` properties, but I require this to be set to the aforestated values as changing them would not allow the user to resize the form. The other approach I tried, which also failed, was by setting the `AutoSize` properties of the aforementioned controls to `false` as to force the child containers of the form to not resize.

Thanks in advance.

PS Screenshot of the concerned form:

[image: Form loaded with the minimal size]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A (blunder) numeric error occurs when calculating the size of the form as the statements `(widthOfWindowInDesignPhase /horizontalResolutionOfTheDisplayInDesignPhase)` and `(heightOfWindowInDesignPhase / verticalResolutionOfTheDisplayInDesignPhase)` return a floating point value that cannot be stored as an integer.

The appropriate statement is as follows:

`this.Size = new Size(Convert.ToInt32(Screen.GetWorkingArea(this.Location).Size.Width * (Convert.ToDouble(widthOfWindowInDesignPhase) / Convert.ToDouble(horizontalResolutionOfTheDisplayInDesignPhase))), Convert.ToInt32(Screen.GetWorkingArea(this.Location).Size.Height * (Convert.ToDouble(heightOfWindowInDesignPhase) / Convert.ToDouble(verticalResolutionOfTheDisplayInDesignPhase))));`